# Finitely generated abelian groups isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Got this on a home assignment and I don't have a clue...
How do I determine if $\mathbb{Z}_{12}\times\mathbb{Z}_{18}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{6}\times\mathbb{Z}_{36}$ are isomorphic? 
Any hints will be very much appreciated!

Comment: The chinese remainder theorem allows you to see clearer. Do you know it?

Comment: you mean $\mathbb{Z}_{6} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3}$ etc..??

Comment: Yeah, exactly that.

Comment: Then what do I say about $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ that is composed of $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3}$ for example?

Comment: No. Have a look at the prerequisites of the theorem. Then apply it accordingly.

Comment: $$\begin{align}&12\times 18=4\times 3\times 2\times 9\\&6\times36=2\times 3\times 9\times 4\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can decompose both groups into cyclic groups of prime power order. This decomposition is unique up to ordering of the factors, so you can decide isomorphy easily having this description at hand.